# Need to minimize a particular window

Tags: powershell

I had tried with below script. While using the below command it will minimize all opened applications. I need minimize only the policy updating window only(Gpupdate.exe). please find the attached gpupdate windows screenshots.[image: GPUPDATE (Policy updating windows i need to minimize]

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "gpupdate.exe"

            Start-Sleep -s 1
            $shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
            $shell.minimizeall()
```

Comment: Why is WMI used to run group policy update?

Comment: ... Why not using [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core)?

Comment: @vonpryz Because some of our user are working through VPN. So i wrote a script file when the user is connecting the VPN. That time gpupdate will run. Some times user has closed the gpupdate cmd file before policy updation complete. So i had planned to minimize the gpupdate windows when its running

Comment: But why use WMI to start a process? Powershell can do that by itself, just as iRon pointed out.

Comment: ... Or `PowerShell.exe -Window Minimized { gpupdate.exe }` and use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management) to open a *new* window if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Set-WindowState.ps1  at  https://gist.github.com/Nora-Ballard/11240204
It utilizes user32.dll  ShowWindowAsync function.

After dot sourcing the function, I can use this in a script:

```
Get-Process -ID $PID | Set-WindowState -State MINIMIZE
Start-Sleep 3
Get-Process -ID $PID | Set-WindowState -State RESTORE
```

As long as my script is running within its own window this works.  You need to have the process that is the window you want to minimize.

Answer (score 0):

When using Windows 11 (and the Windows Terminal), this script may not work properly with using $PID.
To minimize the Windows Terminal, use

```
(Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.name -Match 'Terminal'}) | Set-WindowState -State MINIMIZE
```

The problem is, that it minimizes all Windows Terminal windows.